# Julia Design: Silently Defining/Naming Types in Macros

Tags: types, macros, julia

I am running into a development issue when defining a new feature, dealing with how to "silently define types". Currently I have macros for things like:

```
f = @ode_define begin
dx = a*x - b*x*y
dy = -c*y + d*x*y
end a=>1.5 b=>1 c=3 d=1
```

which will expand to

```
f = (t,u,du) -> begin 
du[1] = 1.5*u[1] - u[1]*u[2]
du[2] = -3*u[2] + u[1]*u[2]
end
```

These define functions for use in ODE solvers. Some features for the ODE solvers require knowing the parameters (i.e. sensitivity analysis requires taking parameter derivatives) so to make it more general I would like to inline the parameters defined with an `=`, and have a "named way of accessing" parameters defined with a `=>`. For example, I would like to instead expand the macro to:

```
f,p = (t,u,du,p) -> begin 
du[1] = p.a*u[1] - p.b*u[1]*u[2]
du[2] = -3*u[2] + u[1]*u[2]
end
```

The question is, how do you define the parameters? I could have the macro also do:

```
type Parameters
  a::Float64
  b::Float64
end
p = Parameters(a,b)
```

then you could only use the macro once per session because each time it would need to define a parameter type. Is there a safe way for naming this type so that the macro could be repeatedly used? Essentially, the parameter type doesn't mean much other than the fact that it's a container for something that holds `a` and `b`, and it can be accessed by name (crucial because I plan on doing things which ask which parameters you'd like to do it to, like bifurcation plots). This is what I mean by "silently"- I'd like the macro to spit out a `p` where `p.a` and `p.b` works, without reference / without the user having to care about how this was defined. Also, this design path has one limitation in that types cannot be defined inside of functions, so this macro cannot be used to define an ODE function inside of a function.

Does Julia offer a good way around these issues that doesn't sacrifice performance? (I could use a dictionary, but that would cause a performance hit).

---

#### Edit

To summarize the design goal, I want something so that macros like the one I show in the beginning could write code that is like:

```
f,p = (t,u,du,p) -> begin 
du[1] = p.a*u[1] - p.b*u[1]*u[2]
du[2] = -3*u[2] + u[1]*u[2]
end
type Parameters
  a::Float64
  b::Float64
end
p = Parameters(a,b)
```

to call

```
solve(f,p,y0)
```

to use in a solver that essentially does

```
for i = 1:numiterations
  y = y + dt*f(t,u,du,p)
end
```

The problem is whether  the proper form for `p` is a type, or whether Julia has something else to "call things with names". If it is a type, how do you get around the fact that types have to have unique names (so the macro can't just trivially expand it to type Parameters since each time it may have different fields) but what to auto-generate a type where you just know the field names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`gensym` creates globally-unique names, which can be spliced in to a **type-definition expression**, for example:

```
Expr(:type, true, gensym(:parameter), Expr(:(::), :x, :Int))
```

> I could use a dictionary, but that would cause a performance hit

Not entirely sure I understand the design goal here, but in your example you are wrapping the instance `p` in the closure. If you make the ODE name a macro parameter (`@ode_def f = ...`), then you could set up a mapping in some global dictionary from `f => f_metadata` with handles to `p` and whatever you might need to modify.

Comment: I added some more details in the edit. I tried `type gensym(:parameters)` with fields `a` and `b` but it says that's an invalid type signature. Is there a way to use `gensym` to generate an expression which can be used in a type signature?

Comment: Updated to answer the specific type-name question. As far as the general design issue: a closure over parameters is very reasonable for integrands / objective functions. However, closing over some opaque type doesn't make sense for modifiable parameters used by the solver rather than one-time constants used in the objective function.

Comment: I think this could work. The main reason why I need to add types is so that I can do things like parameter sensitivity analysis which requires taking derivatives in parameters. I want to be able to tell the solver "give me the sensitivity in the parameter `a`", and thus take the parameter derivative in `a`. That I wouldn't know how to do if the parameters are specified in a closure. But at the same time, the Type of the parameters doesn't really matter, just that it has a field `a`.